# Python script that launches MPV

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I wrote a python script to make the use of mpv easier (cim is the title).

Here's the script:

```
from sh import mpv
cim=input("Cím: ")
a=int(input("with start(1) | without start (2) "))
b=int(input("with sub (1) | without sub(2) "))
if a == 1:
    #w/ start
    c=input("xx:yy:zz : ")
    if b == 1:
        #w/ sub
        sh.mpv(cim,"--sub-file=",d,"start=",c)


    elif b == 2:
        #w/ sub
        sh.mpv(cim,"start=",c)

elif a == 2:
    #nincs start
    if b == 1:
        #w/ sub
        d=input("sub: ")
        sh.mpv(cim,"--sub-file=",d)

    if b == 2:
        sh.mpv(cim)
```

When i try to run it:

```
RAN: 
'/usr/bin/mpv Red Museum.avi --sub-file= eng.srt'

STDOUT:
Error parsing option sub-file (option requires parameter)
Setting commandline option --sub-file= failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the extra space between `--sub-file=` and `eng.srt`. You could fix it by removing the `=` so that `mpv` expects them to be separated by a space. i.e. replace the line

```
sh.mpv(cim,"--sub-file=",d)
```

with

```
sh.mpv(cim,"--sub-file", d)
```

---

If that doesn't work you could get rid of the extra space by using a string concatenation:

```
sh.mpv(cim,"--sub-file=" + d)
```

Comment: Pretty much all command line parsers handle `=` and whitespace in the same way, so using separate arguments is cleaner for sure. Actually, a separate argument is even more likely to work since that's the easy way to get an argument in C code without involving string operations (especially if getopt etc. are not used)

Comment: Yeah, I had a quick try and it seems to work so I'll swap the order of the fixes.